# How to create UTC date in JS?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

When i try to create the date in UTC like `new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 10, 7, 10, 3, 19))` i still receive `Thu Nov 07 2013 12:03:19 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)` where it adds +2 hours. How to create just `2013-11-07 10:03:19` ?

Comment: Date.toLocalString() might help you ;)

Answer (score 3):

The date you created is actually 2013-11-07 10:03:19 UTC, but when you print it, it will print the date in your local timezone. To extract the UTC date, you could try using toUTCString(), like so:

```
Date(Date.UTC(2013, 10, 7, 10, 3, 19)).toUTCString() //"Thu, 07 Nov 2013 10:03:19 GMT"
```

Comment: It's already in UTC, browser prints it in you local timezone.

Comment: The code in your question perfectly creates the date object. A date object, however, may be displayed in any timezone. If you console.log the date object, it will be displayed in your local timezon. You can circumvent this by using the toUTCTString() function

Comment: A universal time (like the date object in many languages) doesn't have a timezone per-say, it can just be printed in different timezones. You can check this place for some useful methods: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please remove  Date.UTC:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2013, 10, 7, 10, 3, 19))
Thu Nov 07 2013 15:33:19 GMT+0530 (IST)
new Date(2013, 10, 7, 10, 3, 19)
Thu Nov 07 2013 10:03:19 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: but it still uses `GMT+0530`. I need it to be 0000.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need toUTCString() ? As seen here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp

Comment: Sorry i haven't seen someone mentioned this above, i will upvote that answer.